# Typescript AJAX Request returning error

Tags: javascript, web-applications, typescript

When I perform a AJAX request in typescript, it works up until I try to retrieve the response:

```
let req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET','img/spritesheet.json',true);
req.send();
req.responseType = 'json';
req.onload=(data)=>{
  var json = data.currentTarget.response;
}
```

It throws me an error:

> "Property 'response' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'

As cool as typescript is, some things make absolutely no sense.  What is the solution to figuring this out?

Comment: Can you please post the complete code here?

Comment: Solution: [don't use typescript](https://gist.github.com/amcdnl/b52e9dd11850eeb8de8f) :P

Comment: That is the complete code for the ajax request.

Comment: Perhaps `json = req.response`

Comment: or just use fetch... `fetch(url).then(res => res.json()).then(json => { ... })`

Comment: Fetch is not advised at this point.  But your json=req.response works.  I love some features of typescript but  some things make absolute no sense

Answer (score 0):

The signature for the callback function of load is:

```
(ev: Event) => any
```

Where [Event](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L7871) is the generic event, which looks like this:

```
interface Event {
    ...
    currentTarget: EventTarget;
    ...
}
```

And [EventTarget](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L7901) is:

```
interface EventTarget {
    addEventListener(type: string, listener?: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, useCapture?: boolean): void;
    dispatchEvent(evt: Event): boolean;
    removeEventListener(type: string, listener?: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, useCapture?: boolean): void;
}
```

Which doesn't have the `response` property.

That's why you get that error, as for how to deal with it, why don't you just use the request object?
It has the [response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/response) and [responseText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseText) properties which you can use, no need to get things from the event object which the callback receives.